# trigger low memory kill (lmk) event

Tags: android

Is there a way to trigger a LMK event on android. Prefer if it can be done programmatically.

I tried by running multiple apps on emulator but never see the lmk event in logcat.

```
adb logcat -b main -s "lowmemorykiller:*"
```

Comment: Try this ADB command `adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEMORY_FULL`